# how to decode base64 NSString(using euc-kr) .. T.T

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have string

this string is encoded with euc-kr..

I try this code

```
NSString *str = MjAxObPitbUgx9C7/bq4yKPAzrfCKLnov/LFzcH2xbTAzCkguPDB/SCw+LDt

NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:str options:0];

NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:kCFStringEncodingEUC_KR];
```

but result is null..

what is wrong..? and I try

```
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:kCFStringEncodingDOSKorean];
```

and

```
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:kCFStringEncodingMacKorean];
```

but result is same..
encoding:kCFStringEncodingMacKorean's result is not korean.;;;;;

Comment: and using NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:kCFStringEncodingDOSKorean]; 
but result is same ..

Comment: If something related to your question then add that code in your question instead of comment. And please specify what is **euc-kr** ??

Comment: euc-kr is a character encoding scheme like utf-8,

Comment: Let me know is this type format is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/encoding) in type properties section. Give me dummy string to test. If my code working properly then I will update the answer.

Comment: P.S. check this post -> https://github.com/hyuni/Blog-Swift/blob/master/Content/iOS%20%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C%20%ED%95%9C%EA%B8%80%20EUC-KR%20Encoding%20%EB%AC%B8%EC%A0%9C.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

Starting with:

```
NSString *str = @"MjAxObPitbUgx9C7/bq4yKPAzrfCKLnov/LFzcH2xbTAzCkguPDB/SCw+LDt";
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:str options:0];
```

What you missed is that you can't really use `kCFStringEncodingEUC_KR` which is a `CFStringEncodings` with `initWithData:encoding:` with expects a `NSStringEncoding`.

You can use `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding()` to convert it:

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingEUC_KR)];
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
```

Output:

```
$>result: 2019년도 학생보호인력(배움터지킴이) 모집 공고
```

If you want to use "natively" the `kCFStringEncodingEUC_KR`, and all the `CFDataRef`, `CFStringRef`, and use the bridge then to convert `CFStringRef` to `NSString`:

```
CFStringRef ref = CFStringCreateWithBytes(nil, [decodedData bytes], [decodedData length], kCFStringEncodingEUC_KR, false);
NSString *result = (__bridge NSString *)ref;
NSLog(@"result: %@", result);
```

Output:

```
$>result: 2019년도 학생보호인력(배움터지킴이) 모집 공고
```

You might need to do some changes, I'm not really familiar with `CFStringCreateWithBytes()`, check the documentation.

Comment: ohhhhh perfect !!
Perfect!
I did not know CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding. Thank you!